apksigner error : Failed to load signer "signer #1" java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
When I use this command to sign an apk file : apksigner sign --ks debug.keystore --ks-key-alias androiddebugkey MyApp.apk, and i got this error as follow:
[tag:tag-name]Failed to load signer "signer #1"
[tag:tag-name]java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
        [tag:tag-name]at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:658)
        [tag:tag-name]at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
        [tag:tag-name]at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
        [tag:tag-name]at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
        [tag:tag-name]at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
        [tag:tag-name]at com.android.apksigner.SignerParams.loadKeyStoreFromFile(SignerParams.java:353)
        [tag:tag-name]at com.android.apksigner.SignerParams.loadPrivateKeyAndCertsFromKeyStore(SignerParams.java:239)
        [tag:tag-name]at com.android.apksigner.SignerParams.loadPrivateKeyAndCerts(SignerParams.java:181)
        [tag:tag-name]at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.sign(ApkSignerTool.java:277)
        [tag:tag-name]at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.main(ApkSignerTool.java:83)

a solution to solve this problem?

Get KeyStoreExplorer and open the keys store in it. Then you can check if the password is correct and the alias matches. And it will display the keystore format. If you know the format tell it to us.

How to get KeyStoreExplorer, i am sure the password and the alias matches

Using your favorite search engine and the search term "KeyStore Explorer" you will directly get to https://keystore-explorer.org

are you kidding？
